# I can't spawn on my own beacon more than once

Tags: battlefield-3

After setting a beacon, dying, and spawning on my own beacon as a non-recon, I can't spawn on my beacon any more after that. Why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The moment you respawn, your beacon gets destroyed. If you want to respawn in a place multiple times, you have to put down a new beacon every time you respawn.

> Squadmates can use the beacon as long as it is intact. In some Rush maps (e.g. Operation Métro), once the current objectives are destroyed, all beacons self-destruct. Players can, however, place new beacons immediately after a base has been taken, allowing for attacks on rear positions. If the original placer dies, the beacon will disappear on respawn regardless if they spawn on the beacon.

([source](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Radio_Beacon))

Comment: So you can respawn multiple times on someone else's beacon, but only once on your own? Wow that kinda sucks, because I never play recon..

Comment: IIRC it doesn't matter how and where you spawn. Respawning destroys your beacon. Similar behavior for C4, which also is removed once you respawn.